# Chromium pepper flash plugin for arm

Tags: flash, arm, chromium

I've ported the chromium for arm with Wayland. Currently my task is to create a flash plugin for it.

How I can see the chromium has internal implementation of the flash. Is it? If it true how can I create my custom build of the plugin (as pepper plugin). If it false where can I find the pepper flash plugin for arm?

Comment: maybe something like this http://hwswbits.blogspot.com/2013/04/flash-on-picuntu-linux-arm.html